# Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript debugging stops working after refreshing browser

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015.

After stating up the application in debug mode I can happily debug my TypeScript code. However, if I make a change to any TypeScript file and then refresh the browser I am no longer able to debug the TS file (all server side C# debugging continues to work fine).

When hovering over the breakpoint it says:

"This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

I've checked and all of the compiled JavaScript files have been loaded in to the script documents so the symbols should still be loaded!

I'm on a Windows 10 laptop at the moment. This never used to be an issue on my previous windows 8.1 laptop with VS2013.

Does anyone have any thoughts as it's really starting to slow me down having to keep restarting my application each time I make a TypeScript change?

Comment: That does look the same happy to close this one as a duplicate (sorry I did search for other instances of this but missed that one).

Comment: Actually turned out my issue was something else but I've added it to the other issue just in case it helps anyone else.